# iTextPdf PKCS#11 PDF Signing With a SafeNet USB Token (ikey 4000)

Tags: certificate, itext

I am currently using the latest version of iText and using the example from the Digital Signing White Paper by Bruno Lowagie.

When I sign a PDF and view it within Adobe Reader the Certificate Chain is not shown and the Signer cannot be validated.  What do I need to do in order to include the Certificate Chain with the Signature so the Signature is automatically validated by Adobe?

The certificate comes from Entrust..which is a member of the Adobe AATL program.  So I am expecting the Signature to be automatically verified without me having to change trust settings within Adobe reader.

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF you signed with that token.

Answer (score 0):

The iText software does not add the intermediate certificate so the chain of trust is broken. Entrust is a member of aatl, but only sells cds certificates